# Segmentation Fault in C Hash Table Implementation

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, hashtable

I'm working on an exercise in which I have to create a hash table implementation in C. So far, I have the basic data structures set up, but I've run into a segmentation fault I can't seem to pinpoint. I've managed to figure out that `ht_del()` is the problem, but further than that I'm not sure.

In case this matters, here's the command I'm using to compile: `gcc main.c hash_table.c -o main -w`

**hash_table.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "hash_table.h"

static ht_item* ht_new_item(const char* k, const char* v){
    ht_item* item = malloc(sizeof(ht_item));
    item->key = strdup(k);
    item->value = strdup(v);
    return item;
}

static void ht_del_item(ht_item* item){
    free(item->key);
    free(item->value);
    free(item);
}

ht_table* ht_new(){
    ht_table* table = malloc(sizeof(ht_table));
    table->size = 53;
    table->count = 0;
    table->items = calloc((size_t) table->size, sizeof(ht_item*));
    return table;
}

void ht_del(ht_table *table){
    for(int k = 0; k < table->size; ++k){
        ht_item* item = table->items[k];
        if(item != NULL) ht_del_item(item);
    }
    free(table->items);
    free(table);
}
```

**hash_table.h:**

```
typedef struct {
    char* key;
    char* value;
} ht_item;

typedef struct {
    int size;
    int count;
    ht_item** items;
} ht_table;
```

**main.c (test code):**

```
#include "hash_table.h"

int main(){
    ht_table* table = ht_new();
    ht_del(table);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running it through `valgrind`?

Comment: None of your `53` items is allocated, yet you are trying to free all of them.

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso I have - `valgrind --track-origins=yes ./main` and I get 
`==12414== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)`

Comment: @EugeneSh. I can see that being the problem, but it works as shown here (and my implementation is pretty much no different): https://github.com/jamesroutley/write-a-hash-table/tree/master/02-hash-table

Comment: OK, I missed the comparison to NULL. Not a very robust method, but in this case should work

Comment: I changed #include "hash_table.h" to #include "hash_table.c" in the main.c file and it worked without any errors. Can you show the error log, if possible.

Comment: I've just realized I made a silly mistake - I forgot to declare `ht_new()` and `ht_del()` in my `hash_table.h` file. Thanks to everyone, especially @DipanshuKumarSuman for pointing me to the source of the error.

Comment: Your compiler should have warned you about that; suggest turning the warnings up. Suggest `ht_new(void)`; the `()` is not a prototype.